# Concatenate the output of 2 commands in the same line in Unix

Tags: bash, unix

I have a command like below

```
md5sum test1.txt | cut -f 1 -d " " >> test.txt
```

I want output of the above result prefixed with `File_CheckSum:`

Expected output: `File_CheckSum: <checksumvalue>`

I tried as follows

```
echo 'File_Checksum:' >> test.txt | md5sum test.txt | cut -f 1 -d " " >> test.txt
```

but getting result as

```
File_Checksum:
adbch345wjlfjsafhals
```

I want the entire output in 1 line

```
File_Checksum: adbch345wjlfjsafhals
```

Comment: In one example, you compute the hash of `test1.txt`.  In another you compute the sum of `test.txt` and attempt to write to that same file.  Are you trying to write to the file that you are computing the sum of? Or is that just a typo?

Comment: Beside the point, but `echo` shouldn't be piped here, since it doesn't produce any output and md5sum doesn't take any input on stdin. It should be connected with `&&` instead.

Comment: Related: [How can I 'echo' out things without a newline?](/q/38021348/4518341)

Comment: No its not a typo. I have only file which test.txt. Say I have 100 lines in the file. In the 101st line I need to write File_Checksum: adbch345wjlfjsafhals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo` writes a newline after it finishes writing its arguments. Some versions of `echo` allow a `-n` option to suppress this, but it's better to use `printf` instead.

You can use a command group to concatenate the the standard output of your two commands:

```
{ printf 'File_Checksum: '; md5sum test.txt | cut -f 1 -d " "; } >> test.txt
```

Note that there is a race condition here: you can theoretically write to `test.txt` before `md5sum` is done reading from it, causing you to checksum more data than you intended. (Your original command mentions `test1.txt` and `test.txt` as separate files, so it's not clear if you are really reading from and writing to the same file.)

Comment: Yes reading and writing to same file. This also works

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%s: %s\n" "File_Checksum:" "$(md5sum < test1.txt | cut ...)" > test.txt
```

Note that if you are trying to compute the hash of `test.txt`(the same file you are trying to write to), this changes things significantly.

Another option is:

```
{
    printf "File_Checksum: "
    md5sum ...
} > test.txt
```

Or:

```
exec > test.txt
printf "File_Checksum: "
md5sum ...
```

but be aware that all subsequent commands will also write their output to `test.txt`.  The typical way to restore stdout is:

```
exec 3>&1
exec > test.txt # Redirect all subsequent commands to `test.txt`
printf "File_Checksum: "
md5sum ...
exec >&3  # Restore original stdout
```

Comment: I need to append File_Checksum:<checksum_value of test.txt> as the last line to the file.

Comment: I tried it as printf "%s: %s\n" "File_Checksum" "$(md5sum test.txt | cut -f 1 -d " ")" >> test.txt and its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command grouping to have a list of commands executed as a unit and  redirect the output of the group at once:

```
{ printf 'File_Checksum: ';  md5sum test1.txt | cut -f 1 -d " " } >> test.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Operator `&&`
e.g. `mkdir example && cd example`

Comment: I think you misunderstood what OP's asking. I just edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).